# while clicking on export button i want to export aspx gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to export ASPxGridView while clicking on a button as export.

I am using code below but not getting the needed results:

```
protected void btn_excel_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxGridViewExporter1 . WriteXlsToResponse();
    }
```

Comment: `i am using this but not getting` What is it doing? What do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. Session["Excel"] - The items that you want to export (In my case I'm storing this in a session).

   using (var exporter = new NpoiExport())
   {

   ```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt = (DataTable)Session["Excel"];
       exporter.ExportDataTableToWorkbook(dt, "Result");

       string saveAsFileName = string.Format("Results-{0:d}.xls", DateTime.Now);


       Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", saveAsFileName));

       Response.Clear();

       Response.BinaryWrite(exporter.GetBytes());

       Response.End();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if you want export the grid view data to excel then do with data table. bind the gridview data into data table and export the data table data to excel.

Comment: welcome, if its helpful, please mark the answer so,others can use the same.

Answer (score 0):

Export to Excel Use this code.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GrdAccess" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="70%" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" CssClass="Grid" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" OnPageIndexChanging="GrdAccess_PageIndexChanging"></asp:GridView>
```

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                //To Export all pages
                GrdAccess.AllowPaging = false;
                this.getProjectDetails();

                GrdAccess.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GrdAccess.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GrdAccess.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdAccess.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GrdAccess.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GrdAccess.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GrdAccess.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }


    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {

        }
```

Comment: this is normal gridview i want aspxgridview

Comment: This is an aspx gridview you can use this code Its working for me.